# Use latest version of Python as default

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, linux, debian

On my Debian server if I run `python -V` it says it's using `Python 2.7.13` even though I have Python 3 installed.

Why isn't it using Python 3 as default by now? I'm trying to deploy a Django app and it's expecting Python 3.

Comment: _Why isn't it using Python 3 as default by now?_ What kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: The Python version the *operating system* uses can't just be changed, not when there are major compatibility issues between Python 2 and 3. You don't tell us what Debian version you are using, [Debian will eventually drop Python 2](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/ch-python3.html), but don't expect the system Python version to meet your needs.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to easily switch between python versions.
Or just use `alias python='/usr/bin/python3.X'`.

Answer (score 5):

> Why isn't it using Python 3 as default by now?

Many distributions have been slow to adopt Python 3 as the default, for a variety of reasons. Luckily, your system default Python should be irrelevant.

Use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/), to bundle a Python interpreter (whichever one you want) and related tools like `pip` along with whatever libraries your application needs.

Python has supported virtualenvs natively via [the `venv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv) since Python 3.3. Alternatively, you can use something like [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [`pew`](https://github.com/berdario/pew) for more features.

There are even tools for installing arbitrary versions of Python like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) (which Pipenv uses if available) or [`pythonz`](https://github.com/saghul/pythonz) (which `pew` uses if available), so you're not limited by whatever version(s) of Python are available via your operating system's package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Debian come with `python3` preinstalled, you can check it through `python3 --version` or `python3 -V`. by default the system use `python2`. To check the default python version : `python -V`

To set `python3` as default, use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3.7
```

`python -V` will print your python3 version.

To update `update-alternatives`, see [this answer on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410851/153195)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need it you can use:

```py
alias python='python3'
```